# PyCharm: why it collects my personal data

Tags: pycharm, licensing, jetbrains-ide, data-collection

Just installed PyCharm Community that should be free under Apache 2.0 license but can not start the software until I agree to share my personal data including phone number, ip address, tax ID, physical address, etc to Jetbrains and associated companies and third parties for different purposes including "promote and market our products" - I do not agree with the terms and did not pass that point.

Why it requires these personal information? Isn't it actually free or open?
Just opened up the website again and can confirm it says "free, open"

Comment: A nasty workaround may be to install it as a flatpak and run it with
`flatpak run --unshare=network com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community`. I say nasty because now you can't use git integration and you need to install the local docs plugin apparently.

Comment: See [Data Sharing in Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-usage-statistics.html) there's a more explicit version of [Data Sharing for IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-usage-statistics.html).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 6):

JetBrains collects a whooooole lot of stuff. I read through the TOS/privacy policy and it seems pretty invasive to me. They also share your data with several third parties  like Amazon, Google, and Microsoft. One of these third parties (New Relic) I was looking at does collect your physical mailing address. Whether that's through JetBrains products or New Relics products (or both) it doesn't say but it is unsettling.

The TOS actually links (https://www.jetbrains.com/legal/privacy/third-parties.html) to a page on JetBrains website listing all the companies they share your data with and there are links on that page that lead to each respective companies **Privacy policies that don't necessarily line up with JetBrains privacy policy.**

Although JetBrains may not do nefarious stuff with your data the third parties may or may not. **You would have to read through 23 different TOS/ Privacy Policies.** JetBrains seems pretty upfront with what they collect in the TOS but it's still pretty vague on how they use it. **There's no telling what those third parties do with your data...**

JetBrains says they collect all this data to "improve and tailor their services to the consumer" and that only anonymous and aggregate data is shared. Supposedly nothing personally identifiable. Any time I read or hear something like that I call shenanigans. That's what all the big data collectors say and that's not entirely truthful. This sucks because apparently PyCharm is the best Python editor out there right now.